# Невозможно открыть проект в JetBrains IDE на Arch Linux+Wayland

Tags: archlinux, jetbrains, wayland

При попытке открыть проект в GoLand на связке `Arch Linux + Wayland + SwayWM`, возникает следующая ситуация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

IDE установлена с использованием `Toolbox App 1.17.7018, Arch Linux  (Linux 5.7.6-arch1-1)`.

Логи IDE:

```
 russia9@runine  ~/.local/bin  ./goland 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2020-06-28 22:31:39,254 [  10515]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Visual Studio" not found [Plugin: com.intellij] 
2020-06-28 22:31:39,256 [  10517]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Eclipse" not found [Plugin: com.intellij] 
2020-06-28 22:31:39,256 [  10517]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "NetBeans 6.5" not found [Plugin: com.intellij] 
2020-06-28 22:31:39,256 [  10517]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Visual Studio" not found [Plugin: com.intellij] 
2020-06-28 22:31:39,293 [  10554]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Visual Studio" not found [Plugin: HtmlTools] 
2020-06-28 22:31:39,305 [  10566]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Eclipse" not found [Plugin: JavaScript] 
2020-06-28 22:31:39,305 [  10566]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Visual Studio" not found [Plugin: JavaScript] 
2020-06-28 22:31:45,303 [  16564]   WARN - openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl - ToolWindow icons should be 13x13. Please fix ToolWindow (ID:  Problems View) or icon jar:file:/home/russia9/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/Goland/ch-0/201.7846.93/lib/icons.jar!/general/warning.svg
```

Файл `vmoptions`:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
-Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true
-Dide.no.platform.update=true
```

Информация о системе:

`````
                   -`                    russia9@runine 
                  .o+`                   -------------- 
                 `ooo/                   OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
                `+oooo:                  Kernel: 5.7.6-arch1-1 
               `+oooooo:                 Uptime: 39 mins 
               -+oooooo+:                Packages: 752 (pacman) 
             `/:-:++oooo+:               Shell: zsh 5.8 
            `/++++/+++++++:              Resolution: 1920x1080 
           `/++++++++++++++:             WM: sway 
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`           Theme: AD-Strawberry [GTK3] 
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`          Icons: AD-Strawberry-Suru [GTK3] 
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`         Terminal: termite 
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.        Terminal Font: Ubuntu Mono 16px 
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.       CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 (12) @ 3.950GHz 
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-       GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590 
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-     Memory: 2693MiB / 16001MiB 
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:
 `++:.                           `-/+/                           
 .`                                 `/
`````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Известная проблема java swing при использовании non-reparenting window managers. См. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java#Missing_text_in_some_applications - обычно сочетание `export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1` с https://tools.suckless.org/x/wmname/ помогает